Pass arguments to a new browser context
When opening a new browser context, the arguments that were used in the fixture do not get loaded. For example, I want extensions to get loaded in all contexts, and not just the original context.
context: async (use) => {
    const pathToExtension = '/path/extension';
    browserArgs.push(--disable-extensions-except=${extensions});browserArgs.push(--load-extension=${extensions});
    const context = await chromium.launchPersistentContext('', {headless: false,args: browserArgs,});
    await context.grantPermissions(grantPermissions);
    await use(context);
}

The code above is in my fixture and the extension gets loaded in the original context but when I open a new context by doing browser.newContext(), the extension is not loaded in there. Is there a way for the extension to get loaded in the new context? Either by adding something in the fixture or by passing in args when calling browser.newContext()?

Can you share a complete [mcve] and context for what you're really trying to accomplish at a high level with this test?
